# How can I export and import a view into table different databases

Tags: mysql, import, export, mariadb

I am trying to export a view from database X to import that into a table on database Y, but I can't do that because some fields are INT an when I try to export the values, blank fields still blank, it is not comming NULL, but if I change that to NULL value, when I try to upload it is bringing the error: 
    - Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_genero_musical' at row 1", 1366)

If I try to import this file without a table created, it is doing the wrong way because the type of the fields is showing all wrong, as TEXT, and INT, just those two types.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `emissora` (
    `id_emissora` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ds_nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `id_tipo_emissora` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_modulacao` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `ds_frequencia` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `nr_alcance` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    `perc_alcance` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `qt_habitantes_alcance` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_streaming` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_id_anatel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_uf` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_uf` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_municipio` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_municipio` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_regiao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_genero_musical` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_emissora`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this query below is what the file is automatic creating:

```
CREATE TABLE `emissora_bkp` (
    `id_emissora` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_nome` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_tipo_emissora` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_modulacao` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_frequencia` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `nr_alcance` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `perc_alcance` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `qt_habitantes_alcance` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_url` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_streaming` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_id_anatel` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_uf` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_uf` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_municipio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ds_municipio` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_regiao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_genero_musical` text DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the CSV file is something like this:

```
id_emissora,ds_nome,id_tipo_emissora,ds_modulacao,ds_frequencia,nr_alcance,perc_alcance,qt_habitantes_alcance,ds_url,ds_streaming,ds_id_anatel,id_uf,ds_uf,id_municipio,ds_municipio,id_regiao,id_genero_musical
4,Cultura,null,FM,102.5,0,null,null,http://www.cultura.fm.br/,,null,16,PR,2969,Cultura,5,null
6,Abdallah,null,FM,104.1,55,null,null,http://www.abdallahfm.com.br/,http://server3.webradios.com.br:9338/9338,57dbac33ef411,16,PR,2911,Abdallah,5,3
7,Aline,null,FM,93.7,0,null,null,http://www.alinefm.com.br,http://controleflash.omegasistemas.net:8356/;stream.mp3,57dbac367dbbc,16,PR,3147,Aline,5,3
8,Amiga,null,FM,101.3,40,null,null,http://www.amiga101.com.br,http://stream4.painelvox.com.br:7052,57dbac337965d,16,PR,2878,Amiga,5,3
```

I am using MySQL workbench.

Comment: Are you using mysqlworkbench import wizard or load data infile? is  `emissora_bkp` supposed to be and exact copy if  `emissora`? Why are you using a view?

Comment: I am using MySQLWorkbench https://imgur.com/ip06o6g this two button to export and import, I am doing that because I am migrating older database to a new one, then I create this view with some joins to group the data that will be different now